# Prevent "space" into insert

Tags: php, mysql, string

I want to prevent "first space" into inserting in database when user types. For example , ' ball' is not allowed. "ball" is allowed. How Can I do this ?

Comment: use `trim($variable)` on your variables before you write them to your database.

Comment: u can do this by using `trim()`

Answer (score 2):

you could use [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), like:

```
$your_var = trim($your_var); //trims spaces from front and last
```

or

```
$your_var = ltrim($your_var); //removes space from front
```

Comment: Nice one, `ltrim` as the OP wanted!

Comment: yea, added that too.. :)

Comment: Will it be same for this example ? Suppose , I want to insert 'my ball' , but not ' my ball'

Comment: @liza, yes, you could do ltrim($your_string); if you want to remove whitespace from beginning or your string...

Comment: @liza, please take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`LTRIM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_ltrim) or [`TRIM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) on mysql side

```sql
INSERT INTO Table1 (column1)
SELECT LTRIM(' ball')
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff1e1/1)** demo

You can even enforce it with a simple trigger like this

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tg_table1_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON Table1
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.column1 = LTRIM(NEW.column1);
```

That way no matter how a record is being inserted (with application code or manually) leading spaces will be removed.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/375ba/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

Use [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) for removing spaces from a string.

`ltrim()` - Remove spaces from left

`rtrim()` - Remove spaces from rigth

`trim()` - Will reomve spaces from both sides

Answer (score 0):

The trim() function removes whitespaces and other predefined characters from both sides of a string.

Related functions:

- ltrim() - Removes whitespace or other predefined characters from the
  left side of a string
- rtrim() - Removes whitespace or other predefined characters from the
  right side of a string

  ";
  echo "With trim: " . trim($str);
  ?>

Hope to be helpful...